# move lower and upper floats of __m128

Tags: c++, x86, simd

How do I move lower and upper floats of `__m128` into two `__m128` and zero clear other halves.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't specify, I'm assuming the intention is to use SSE intrinsics. I'll also assume at least SSE2 is available since that's basically the baseline set by x86-64 these days…

A quite literal way of doing what you describe above would be to simply copy the lower 64 Bits of the input and zero the upper 64 Bits via `_mm_move_epi64()`

```cpp
__m128 lo2(__m128 x)
{
    return _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_move_epi64(_mm_castps_si128(x)));
}
```

and use `_mm_move_sd()` to copy the upper 64 Bits of the input and copy the lower 64 Bits from a zero

```cpp
__m128 hi2(__m128 x)
{
    return _mm_castpd_ps(_mm_move_sd(_mm_castps_pd(x), _mm_setzero_pd()));
}
```

working example [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOQCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIRmzyAZ2ydURAg2rZ6mAMLp2AVwC29YTswAZAvWwA5UwCNspENIDs5AA7olxTXoDYzNhX38NBhs7RxMXN09lVWx1QKYiVlIiYNNzbiS1SPp0zKJoh2dXdy8lDKyc0Pza0vLY%2BOqASmV0I1JULgByGQBmW1RjHABqSWG9AA8TE1siUlsAOiQZ3EkABgBBXYP9gH1jk25pAA5J9nRpCFPzq8m5jsPJD3l9yZ/J0mwiL16JMziZjmxav4Lpdjt4lA9Fmd0AA3bDHbDeAgANl4CLBEKIcOOUKuEFeHTewy%2BBw8ABF3icztDJkgCPdHszXu9Podfn8AUCQYiCd5MLD4aCkajiZg8eDWLUiaKyV0hWCVEQAF6udCw2UUynUj70/YMg7SUb0cZGKYzPSaWr/VgmLZm5aTEysWwQN6mnnfX4c55zabDWnTT6TfKTaTkSbDOO8CP0qlmvlB663UPh273LmpgM/DMsgjZkt5w1p361TAgNA9IihvR2m7oSQAVlkww74btLZksem0mkTZbtw7smkPdHsyHg4HM70rYn3GnfdnA7jC/XS/HnZ2a9mLZrdcs7Bm1L5J/rRkbO5LE%2B77d7R43w63w8XD87U%2BfX83c5fqyK6Hs2b7zp%2B97AfuoHHkQtYgGeF7ciaewDF07AgAM7YDOQ5gDDsuHoFhzZyAokxKD0fTYEOwzcLhRBYYRFLkAA1iA7Y7CIWG8LhJggFi7ZrFiACc3AeJclzttIOLDLwsb4YR5DEQMuFKCAXGMQR6HkHAsAoA23i3pQ1AYCYmKcG4%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%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: Why don't just use ```_mm_move_epi64(x)``` in ```lo2``` and ```_mm_move_sd(x, _mm_setzero_pd())``` in ```hi2```?

Comment: @scicyb Yeah I just realized that as well. Updated my answer…

Comment: With SSE4.1 it can be more efficient to `_mm_blend_ps` with `_mm_setzero_ps`; `blendps` can run on more execution ports in Intel CPUs than `movsd`.  For some reasons Intel CPUs decode `movsd reg,reg` to run on port 5 only, like a shuffle.  https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/.  (Or course `andps` / `andps` can also relieve port 5 pressure, at the cost of a constant).  But yes, +1, `movq` and `movsd` intrinsics should compile efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

What about `_mm_movelh_ps()` and `_mm_movehl_ps()`, which, combined with a register of all zeros, does exactly what you want?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <x86intrin.h>

void print_vec(__m128 a) {
  alignas(16) float res[4];
  _mm_store_ps(res, a);
  std::cout << res[0] << '\t' << res[1] << '\t' << res[2] << '\t' << res[3]
            << '\n';
}

int main() {
  __m128 vec = _mm_set_ps(4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);

  __m128 lo = _mm_movelh_ps(vec, _mm_setzero_ps());
  __m128 hi = _mm_movehl_ps(vec, _mm_setzero_ps());

  std::cout << "Orig:\t";
  print_vec(vec);
  std::cout << "Lower:\t";
  print_vec(lo);
  std::cout << "Upper:\t";
  print_vec(hi);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this produces:

```
Orig:   1   2   3   4
Lower:  1   2   0   0
Upper:  0   0   3   4
```

Comment: Yes, you could use those to replace the low or high qword with zeros, but those are both shuffle instructions so run on only 1 execution port on Intel.  (vs. `movq xmm0, xmm1` zero-extending the low half running on any of the 3 vector ALU ports).  Also, `movq` has the advantage of copying to a new register, but your way would need an extra `movaps` to avoid destroying `vec`.  (Because it's needed later for zeroing the other half).

Comment: On current Intel CPUs, though, `movhlps` to zero the low half is just as efficient as `movsd` to zero the low half (from @Michael Kenzel's answer).  And saves 1 byte of code size because it's SSE1 ps instead of SSE2 pd.

Comment: @PeterCordes I suppose intelligent scheduling in a real-use program would help with the port pressure? They're both listed as having throughput and latency of 1 so it can't be that bad even if not as far as I understand things (granted, that's not very well).

Comment: out-of-order exec usually means instruction ordering doesn't matter, only dependency patterns.  Although uops do get executed oldest-ready-first, so the critical (latency) path can get delayed by resource conflicts for an execution port with instructions that didn't need to run that early.  In a loop you either bottleneck on one specific port (or group of ports) or you bottleneck on something else (often front-end); instruction order can't help with that.  `movq xmm,xmm` is 0.33c latency on Intel as far back as Core2, and 0.25 on Zen https://www.uops.info/html-instr/MOVQ_0F7E_XMM_XMM.html

Comment: Anyway, this answer was a good idea that's worth considering, but it turns out not to be as efficient as `movq` for the low half on almost all CPUs in most situations.  (On Nehalem if bottlenecked on latency, the bypass delay from FP->int->FP could make `movq` a bad choice.  No other CPUs have bypass latency as high as 2 cycles.  But in that case, for a Nehalem-specific version you'd want SSE4.1 `insertps` to copy and zero without needing a zeroed register.